# When can we exchange expectation and maximum for asymptotic results?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, asymptotics

Motivated in the [analysis of algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12830/can-expected-depth-of-an-element-and-expected-height-differ-significantly), consider the following setup.

Assume we have discrete random variables $X^{(n)}_1, \dots, X^{(n)}_n$ which we can not assume to be identical or independent. The distribution of the $X^{(n)}_i$ can depend on both $i$ and $n$. Let

$\qquad\displaystyle X^{(n)} = \max_{i \in [1..n]} X^{(n)}_i$

the maximum of those. Assume furthermore that we have shown that $\mathbb{E}[X^{(n)}_i] \in O(f(n))$ for all $i$ as $n \to \infty$, so in particular $\mathbb{E}[X^{(n)}_i]$ depends on $n$. Here, $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a "simple" increasing function, e.g. polynomial or  polylogarithmic¹.

Under which conditions can we conclude that

$\qquad\displaystyle \mathbb{E}[X^{(n)}] \in O\bigl(\max_{i \in [1..n]} \mathbb{E}[X^{(n)}_i]\bigr) = O(f(n))$?

---

1. Actually, we'd have $\mathbb{E}[X^{(n)}_i] = g(i,n)$ for some "nice" function $g$. Since our interest is in an asymptotic bound in $n$, we drop the dependence on $i$ ensuring that $f(n)$ is an upper bound on $g(i,n)$ for all $i \leq n$ (up to a constant factor).

Comment: There are quite good bounds (growing sublinearly in $n$) if you can assume that the variables come from a common distribution for which moments are finite, in particular, if the variance is finite.  I think the proofs may carry through to your setup, as long as the finite moment condition holds.  Is this likely?

Comment: @AndrásSalamon The $X_i$ have the same distribution up to its parameters. Since their support is typically finite in my application, we can assume finite moments.

Comment: @Did Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9346/discussion-between-raphael-and-did)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Note:* this answer was to an earlier version of the question.  My understanding was that the distribution of $X_j$ was fixed.  The current version of the question indicates that the parameters of its distribution depend on $n$ also.  The bounds still apply, but may be less directly useful for this scenario.)

---

Since you are presumably interested in how the maximum behaves as $n$ grows, let $X_{(n)}$ denote the $n$-th order statistic, i.e. the maximum among the $n$ random variables.  Let $\mu_j = E[X_j]$ and $\sigma_j^2 = \text{Var}[X_j]$ for each $j$, and let $\overline{\mu} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \mu_j$.  Also let $S^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n (X_j - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2$ denote the sample variance.

It is known (see pp. 48–49 of Arnold and Balakrishnan) that
 $$
  \overline{\mu} + E[S]/\sqrt{n-1} \le E[X_{(n)}] \le \overline{\mu} + E[S]\sqrt{n-1}.
 $$
Further, Arnold and Groeneveld showed that
 $$
  \overline{\mu} \le E[X_{(n)}] \le \overline{\mu} +
   \sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n (Var[X_j] + (\mu_j - \overline{\mu})^2)},
 $$
if this expression is more useful for your application.

- B. C. Arnold and N. Balakrishnan, *Relations, Bounds and Approximations for Order Statistics.* Lecture Notes in Statistics **53**. Springer-Verlag, 1989.
- B. C. Arnold and R. A. Groeneveld, *Bounds on expectations of linear systematic statistics based on dependent samples*, Mathematics of Operations Research **4** 441–447.

If the variables are independent and have the same mean and variance as well, then [Gumbel](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177728847) and also [Hartley and David](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177728848) showed that $E[X_{(n)}] \le \mu + \sigma(n-1)/\sqrt{2n-1}$, although your last comment indicates this doesn't apply.  Some further bounds were derived by Downey.

- Peter J. Downey, *Distribution-free bounds on the expectation of the maximum with scheduling applications*, Operations Research Letters **9**, 1990, 189–201.  doi:[10.1016/0167-6377(90)90018-Z](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0167-6377%2890%2990018-Z)

More information seems to be needed about the precise behaviour of $\text{Var}[X_j]$ or $\mu_j$, but this should get you part of the way there.

Comment: That looks helpful, thanks! To be clear (because Did seems to have missed that part), this holds if the resp. distributions of the $X_i$ change as $n$ grows? The way I see it, the inequality should for every fixed $n$ then, to I should get asymptotics if I can bound variance and expectation of the $X_j$ appropriately.

Comment: If $X_j$ depends on $j$ as well as on $n$, then these bounds may be less helpful -- you may need some bounds on how fast $\text{Var}[X_j]$ grows with $n$, for instance.

Comment: Sure, I don't think more can be expected. In the particular instance I have been investigating, I know that $\mathbb{E}[X_i^r] \sim (\ln n)^r$ for all $i$ and $r \in \mathbb{N}$ (and $Var[X_i] \sim \ln n$). This does not seem to lead to a logarithmic bound on $\mathbb{E}[X]$, but $\sqrt{n \log n}$ is a start. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

The following method can yield bounds stronger than the one András cites but requires even more knowledge about the distribution of the $X^{(n)}_i$. The idea is to use bounds on the tail probabilities of the $X^{(n)}_i$ to bound the tail of their maximum $X^{(n)}$.

We start with a lemma from Cover/Thomas [1] (Lemma 11.9.1, [p392 in 2nd edition](http://books.google.de/books?id=EuhBluW31hsC&lpg=PA347&pg=PA392#v=onepage&q&f=false)):

> **Lemma**
>
> Let $Y$ be any random variable and let $M_Y(z)$ be the moment generating function of $Y$, i. e. $M_Y(z) = \mathbb{E}[e^{zY}]$.
>
> Then
>
> $\qquad\displaystyle \Pr[Y \geq a] \leq \frac{M_Y(z)}{e^{za}}$
>
> for all $z \geq 0$.

So if we can find the moment generating function of $X^{(n)}_i$ (e.g. via its probability generating function), we get bounds whose quality we can adjust by choosing both $a = c \cdot f(n)$ and $z$ appropriately. If all goes well, we get a uniform bound of the form

$\qquad \displaystyle \Pr[X^{(n)}_i \geq c \cdot f(n)] \leq \alpha(n) \in o(n^{-1})$.

Note that, in particular, $\alpha$ does not depend on $i$. Then, we can conclude that

$\qquad \displaystyle \Pr[X^{(n)} \geq c \cdot f(n)] \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \Pr[X^{(n)}_i \geq c \cdot f(n)] \leq n \cdot \alpha(n) \in o(1)$

using $\sigma$-subadditivity. From this, the desired bound $\mathbb{E}[X^{(n)}] \in O(f(n))$ follows immediately.

---

1. Elements of Information Theory by T.M. Cover and J.A. Thomas

Comment: Thank you [M.B.M.](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/15763/m-b-m) for [pointing me towards the lemma](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/80872/3330).

Comment: A similar bound is given by Theorem IX.2.3 in [Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html) by P. Flajolet and S. Sedgewick (2009). This one uses the probability generating function.